# D3.JS - svg shown in github editor, but not in Visual Studio Code - why?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

As a D3 beginner, I am currently making a tutorial, using the Github editor. So far everything works. However, when I use the code one to one in my IDE, the **black circles** are not displayed? How can this be??

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is just a test</p>
    <svg id="container" width="960" height="500" ></svg>
       
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js++

```
import {select, forceSimulation, forceManyBody, forceLink, forceCenter} from "d3";

const nodes = [
    {"id": "Alice"},
    {"id": "Bob"},
    {"id": "Carol"}
  ];

  const svg = select("#container");
  const width = +svg.attr("width");
  const height = +svg.attr("height");
  const centerX = width / 2;
  const centerY = height / 2;

  const links = [
    {"source": 0, "target": 1}, // Alice → Bob
    {"source": 1, "target": 2} // Bob → Carol
  ];

const simulation = forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("charge", forceManyBody())
    .force("link", forceLink(links))
    .force("center", forceCenter(centerX, centerY));

const circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(nodes).enter().append("circle").attr("r", 30);

simulation.on("tick", () => {
    circles.attr("cx", d=>d.x)
    circles.attr("cy", d=>d.y)
});
```

Comment: Because Visual Studio Code simply does not support SVG rendering out of the box.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Robert. I have installed several relevant SVG and D3 packages, but the problem still persists. I also unfortunately can't find a suitable answer on Google. So I still do not understand what I did wrong, what is missing, or what I can do now :(

Comment: Here's an analogy. You enter a building and can't find the stairs to get to the first floor. You ask someone and they say this is a bungalow. So *what did you do wrong*? You didn't realise you were in a bungalow and therefore that there was no first floor. *What is missing?* The first floor I suppose. *What can you do now?* Try using a different building if you need one that has a first floor.

Comment: I'm surprised that you're seeing anything at all, because there is no element with the ID `container`.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the index.html :/

Comment: Please update the question to explain how you trying to render the page via VS Code. E.g. I use Live Preview as an extension - what do you do?